# How to search automatically when opening the start menu in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

On Windows 10, if you type anything after opening the start menu it will search. How do I get this behaviour on Windows 11?

Comment: For me, the same thing happens on Win11

Comment: You can open the Search icon (lower left) and then start typing.  Windows 11 is different.  ...  You can also open the Start Menu and just type. It shows at the top of the menu. It becomes very familiar very quickly.

Comment: I guess it's because I have an issue with my Windows 11 start menu then. The search doesn't work for me. The start menu instantly closes when I click on search.

Answer (score 0):

> The search doesn't work for me. The start menu instantly closes when I
> click on search

Search works fine on my two production machines and on my Insider machine.

You need to repair your system :

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.

Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.
Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.

Proceed normally answering the prompts.
The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

**(1) Keep Everything: Best** if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

**(2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.** Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

**(3) Keep Nothing:** Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how I fixed it but I think running the DISM commands in CMD fixed it.

Open CMD and run:

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Restart computer after